# Css only id or full path

Tags: css, browser

What is better? Only `#logo` or full path `body #header #navigation #logo`?
Which of them is better for the browser and for the CSS parser. Which is faster? Which is the best practice?

Comment: `#logo` is best practice. I'm writing this comment slower than all my browsers take to simultaneously parse both selectors a million times over.

Answer (score 5):

IDs are unique, therefore `#logo` is the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If the style of your `#logo` does not depend on its path, you better don't use the path because your CSS is much more flexible without it.